# what could be the reasons that a neural network stuck on a high loss while training

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, regression

I'm training a neural network to predict one continuous value. so my problem is a regression Problem, it should be simple I have 3 or 4 features and the target I want to predict is a value of an angle so between 0 and 360. I'm using pytorch/skorch for that and I think it is a pretty cool API, I standardize/normalize the features before feeding it to the network, I tried different architectures, different hyperparams etc.. but I noticed that the Network start learining good so the loss start decreasing in a good way but when it reach 6000 or 7000 it somehow stuck there and the Network have a hard time to learn further. Now I don't know why this is happening and I'm seeking for advice or guide. I'm sure I have no errors in my code because I tried fitting only 10 data points from my dataset and that worked ( the NN achieved to overfit on those 10 samples) but when I take the whole dataset which containing 10000 data points, the network stucks at that high loss value and it is having a hard time to train further, I'm not sure what can cause this, I mean at least a Neural network should overfits on training data but my Network doesn't even achieve to overfit. Anyone please know what can be the reasons that lead to such behavior or what can I try other than batch normalization, more complex architectures, different hyperparams?

Comment: Can you provide the architecture you are using? Like the no of layers and units in each layer

Comment: @ManuSPillai I tried so many combinations but none of them worked. I tried from 1 to 10 layers and from 6 to 1024 neurons

Comment: There is a saying among machine learning practitioners, for 90% of tasks, we wont be needing a neural network. As you are saying, the input features is 3 or 4. Jumping directly to non-linear models like nn is never a good practice. Have you tried a linear regression model for your data? if not then you should start from a linear model with some EDA if required.

Comment: But if applying a neural network is a compulsion, then for a data like that, a DNN with 2 layers and 5-10 neurons will be sufficient i believe(with mse loss [obviously]).
But as you said the output variables are 0-360, meaning bounded in some sense, I have seen literatures where a cross entropy loss is used after normalizing the label between 0-1. They say,  its more stable than a mse in those cases. Moreover, these are just suggestion that i might have done if in your condition.

Comment: I strongly believe the loss is not decreasing due to your model being too complex, or getting stuck at a nasty local mimima. (as you already claimed your code to be correct). Have a proper initialization to your model. The best working so far upto my knowledge is glorot uniform. It might help if the case is the latter. 

Let me know, if some of these helped you getting the loss down.

Comment: @ManuSPillai thanks for your suggestions. it is mandatory that I use NN for my Project, also my data have a strong non linearity so a simple linear model will not achieve to fit it, I already tried gradient boost and random forest but it didnt work. can you please explain more how can I use entropy loss in this case? as my problem is regression and not a classification problem, I'm trying to predict an angle so maybe some value would be 191,234 and as far as I know entropy loss will not help in this case

Comment: the initialization Idea seems good though I didn't think about it and didn't think it will make much a diference as my loss value is very high. I applied my implementation only on 50 examples from my dataset and it worked, the nn achieved to overfit the data so that's mean there is no problem with the implementation. The problem starts when I train my model with my whole dataset which is also not so big(only 10000 samples or rows if you d like to think of it as rows) so if it overfits 50 samples it should be also able to overfit 10000 that's what confusing me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203933/discussion-between-manu-s-pillai-and-basilisk).